# How do you return promises from functions that don't allow for return values without using deferred APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I asked [Is wrapping a promise in a promise an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681315/is-wrapping-a-promise-in-a-promise-an-anti-pattern) a few days ago which led me to this.

In that case I had to deal with a `setTimeout`, which doesn't allow for return values. Thankfully you can deal with this by using the built in `delay` function (at least for bluebird promises).

But what about for something like a gulp task? Also inspired by another question: [How to pass an object from gulpfile to another JavaScript file in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702620/how-to-pass-an-object-from-gulpfile-to-another-javacript-file-in-nodejs)

```
var stuff;
gulp.task('LoadYamlFiles', function() {
  // do stuff
  stuff = 'blah';
});

module.exports = { stuff };
```

The export wouldn't be 'blah' because the gulp task runs asynchronously. This can be solved using promises.

One way you could do it is using a deferred (code from https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns):

```
// setTimeout that returns a promise
function delay(ms) {
    var deferred = Promise.pending();
    setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    }, ms);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And this actually isn't considered an anti-pattern according to their wiki, but I see the usage of `deferred` discouraged a lot. This seems important to acknowledge because bluebird doesn't even have the `.pending()` method in their API anymore, meaning I can't really do it this way even if I wanted to.

However you can't do:

```
var stuff;
var myPromise = gulp.task('LoadYamlFiles', function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // do stuff
    stuff = 'blah';
    resolve(stuff);
  })
});

module.exports = { myPromise };
```

because the return value of the anonymous function isn't what `myPromise` will contain. Also it would cause the problems you can see here [Does a gulp task have to return anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079118/does-a-gulp-task-have-to-return-anything)

So how do you deal with these cases where normally you would use the de facto deprecated `deferred` pattern?

Comment: afaik, "deferred" is only "deprecated" as a specific thing in jQuery, not as a concept in general. that said, you can make a promise outside the callback and resolve it from inside the callback...

Comment: I use `var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));`, and then avoid setTimeout everywhere else, because of its poor error handling characteristics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You named your variable `myPromise`, that's a first hint that whatever is on the other side of the `=`, it should be a promise. So let's start with

```
var myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // todo
});

module.exports { myPromise };
```

Now, let's fill in the details.

```
var myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  gulp.task('LoadYamlFiles', function() {
    let stuff = 'blah';
    resolve(stuff);
  });
});
```

A bit of refactoring gives us

```
let myPromise = new Promise(resolve => 
  gulp.task('LoadYamlFiles', () => resolve('blah')));
```

I'm sure this isn't a real usecase, but it can apply nonetheless.

Also see:

- [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I agree with this, and actually I recall that I've done it a few times before. Out of curiosity is there a way to do it without wrapping the entire task in a promise?

Comment: But that's exactly what a promise is. A promise is a proxy to a value, "I *promise* you that a value (or an error) will arrive sometime in the future". So you basically, need the promise wrapper. Normally, it's better to wrap the whole thing in a function and call it, allows you to pass parameters into the Promise constructor via closure.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zrg01t65/1/? Obviously the example doesn't actually work since fiddle doesn't have gulp, but is valid?

Comment: No, where does your `resolve()` come from in the second function? Read the first question/answer I linked.

Comment: Thanks for all your help today. I ended up taking my broken idea from above and making this: https://github.com/AriaFallah/pwrap. Not sure how useful it'll be if at all, but it was pretty nice being able to make my first module for npm. I appreciate you answering everything :D

Comment: @AR7 If you're working server-side, I recommend that you use Bluebird (a promise library), it has awesome helper features, it's faster than native promises, and it can promisify callback functions (and even entire objects)